# In java, how do I make the while loop run until the condition is satisfied multiple times?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to make a program where the user can input the target as well as the amount of times he wants to hit the target. The problem is that I dont know how to make the while loop run more than once (satisfy the condition more than one time).

```
Scanner target = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter dice target (1-10):");
int targetNumber = target.nextInt(); 

Scanner required = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of required matches: ");
int requiredMatches = target.nextInt();

int number = (int) (1 + 10 * Math.random());
int sum = 1;
if (targetNumber > 10) { 
    System.out.println("Error"); 
}
else {
    while (number != targetNumber) { 
        System.out.println("Your number is " + number);
        number = (int) (1 + 10 * Math.random());
        ++sum;
    }
    System.out.println("You reached your target " + requiredMatches + " times in " + sum + " tries.");
}
```

The code lets me match the target only once, but I want it to be able to obtain the target value [RequiredMatches] times before it stops.

Comment: `while (RequiredMatches > 0) { ` and adjust RequiredMatches in the loop maybe (as a side note you should respect usual naming convention)

Comment: It's not clear what your intended logic is.  But, in normal English, what is the specific condition that drives the loop?  Usually the code you write should *very closely* approximate the description of the code.  For example, if you want a loop to continue "while x is less than 10" then the resulting code would be: `while (x < 10)`

Comment: As an aside: please respect Java coding conventions: variables and attributes normally start with a lowercase letter. Also you may want to take a look at [`Random.nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-). This can eliminate some casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number matches, then reduce the tries by 1.

```
Scanner Required = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of required matches: ");
int RequiredMatches = Target.nextInt();

int Number = (int) (1 + 10 * Math.random());
int sum = 1;
if (NumberTarget > 10) { 
  System.out.println("Error"); 
} else {
    while ((Number != NumberTarget) || (RequiredMatches > 0)) { 
        System.out.println("Your number is " + Number);
        Number = (int) (1 + 10 * Math.random());
        ++sum;
        if (Number==NumberTarget) {
            RequiredMatches--;
        }
        System.out.println("You reached your target " + RequiredMatches + " times in " + sum + " tries.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, @rathan, i believe so! just had to make som changes in the last printed line. sorry if my original question wasn't clear. i observed that i got some complaints on this. i'm very new to java, the syntax and programming in general.